# How can I send fireup journey builder trigger using php code not curl

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have build the journey builder interaction shown on ExactTarget. Everything looks good. Now in the exercise it uses curl command. Is there way to fire up the the journey builder interaction using php code. Bear in mind I used data extensions. This is the exercise
https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started/sending-your-first-email/sending-your-first-email.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, your php will include curl lib commands, as that's typically how php developers make calls to endpoints server-side.  (I don't think functions like file_get_contents() are powerful enough.)  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php  Just make sure your config settings have curl enabled.  UI-side you can just fire the trigger from jquery or other hxr lib.  If you really want to avoid curl you can try using fopen() with stream_context_create(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: @adlan, were you successful?  If so, what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Drew's previous answer, it's unclear how you intend to Fire the Event. Assuming you plan to use cURL and don't need to serialize any Event data (that is, you just want records in a Data Extension to enter the Interaction), then I would create a new Interaction in Automation Studio with a Fire Event Activity (that uses the Data Extension you created).

[image: fire event activity in Automation Studio]

Once you have done this, you can test by firing the event manually from the Automation by clicking the 'Run Once' button, or test by using the following cURL command with a 'Perform' Action to request a SOAP envelope:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: Perform" -d @request.xml https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
```

Ensure that you replace `webservice.s7.exacttarget.com` with the endpoint that you are using for your account instance. Create a new file named 'request.xml' with the following envelope, replacing `automation-external-key` with the External Key of the Automation (available from the Automation Summary page).

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
     <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">access-token-here</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="Automation">
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey>automation-external-key</CustomerKey>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note that you will need to replace `access-token-here` with the OAuth accessToken retrieved from the [Fuel Auth Service](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/auth/requestToken.html), or alternatively you can use a basic username/password in your header if your account user is API enabled:

```
<soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6421ac0b-a454-42a3-99f7-a77ace024446">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

One thing to note is that when using Automation Studio to fire an Event, only **new records** in the Data Extension will be included in the Event.

Also, you will need to ensure that the Data Extension that you are using is used as the Event Data Source in the Interaction Trigger, so the Trigger can listen for the Event when it's fired.

Comment: No problem, let me know how you go. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it works for you, for the benefit of other users looking for the same answer.